# Feeding the Omni Plant with Supernatural fish

Tags: the-sims-3, sims-3-supernatural

I've completed the Omni Plant opportunity and got the seeds. Then I fed the plant with fairy damsel fish.

However, the plant is stuck in harvest state with no fish appearing. The same goes with Luminous salamander and toad.

Is there anything I can do?